# sliding puzzle code

Tags: java, eclipse, puzzle, sliding

Our group project is to create a sliding puzzle game using Java Eclipse. We have the code to create a 3x3 grid with the same picture(its supposed to be one picture but split into 9 pieces but well learn that later on). My part is to create a mouse listener that clicks the selected 'tile' and then displays a message testing to see if the selected tile was clicked correctly. (Example: if user clicks tile 1, message displays "tile 1 is clicked") I think I will have to create individual mouse listeners for each tile. Any suggestions?

Heres the code:

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.event.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;

   public class Puzzle 
   {
// Initialize the Frame for the Puzzle
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Puzzle");
private JPanel puzzlePanel = new JPanel( null );
private JLabel status;


// Itemize Menu
private JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
private JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File");
private JMenuItem menuFileNew = new JMenuItem("New Game");
private JMenuItem menuFileQuit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
private JMenu menuHelp = new JMenu("Help");
private JMenuItem menuHelpAbout = new JMenuItem("About");

// Variables
// Easy(3) Medium(4) Hard(5)
private int dimm = 3;
private int spacing = 5;
private int tileDimm = 96;

// Constructor
public Puzzle() 
{
    status = new JLabel("Default");
    frame.add(status,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    // Build Menu
    frame.setJMenuBar(menu);
    menuFile.add(menuFileNew);
    menuFile.add(menuFileQuit);
    menuHelp.add(menuHelpAbout);
    menu.add(menuFile);
    menu.add(menuHelp);

    // Panel
    puzzlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((dimm*tileDimm)+(spacing*(dimm+1)),(dimm*tileDimm)+(spacing*(dimm+1))) );
    frame.add(puzzlePanel);

    // Puzzle Logic
    PuzzleLogic puzzleLogic = new PuzzleLogic(dimm);



    Tile[][] tiles = puzzleLogic.createTileArray();
    puzzleLogic.shuffleTiles(tiles);
    for(int i = 0; i < dimm; i++) 
    {
        for(int ii = 0; ii < dimm; ii++) 
        {
            puzzlePanel.add(tiles[i][ii].getLabel());
            int x = i*tileDimm+(spacing*(i+1));
            int y = ii*tileDimm+(spacing*(ii+1));
            tiles[i][ii].getLabel().setBounds(x,y,tileDimm,tileDimm);

            System.out.print(tiles[i][ii].getContent() + " ");
        }
    }

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    puzzlePanel.addMouseListener(handler);
}

// create listener - inner class
class HandlerClass implements MouseListener
{

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {

        status.setText(String.format("Tile 1 is clicked"));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        status.setText(String.format(" "));

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

}

public void launch() 
{
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack(); //Adjusts panel to components for display
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
}

// Calls Everything to Action
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle();
    puzzle.launch();
}
```

}

Comment: Read my article, [2048 Game in Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=516), to see one way of creating a sliding game.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have already makes one listener for the whole puzzle. So in the `mouseClicked` handler you could calculate the mouse's position relative to the position in the puzzle, calculate if it's in the top/bottom/middle third and left/right/middle third and from there you can compute which piece the player clicked on?

You can get the coordinates of the mouse position by using `e.getX()` and `e.getY()`.

Comment: im confused on how to calculate if its in the top bottom middle lol

Comment: all i want to do is after i run it and say i click the upper left tile it displays "tile 1". if i click the middle box on the top row it displays "tile 2." if the upper right tile is clicked is displays "tile 3" and so on lol

Answer (score 0):

You can get X and Y coordinate of Mouse Click and then divide with width and height respectively you can get the block number.. but it will return X: 0,1,2 Y:0,1,2 [for a 3x3 block].. So make sure to add one (+1) at the last .Your code will somewhat look like:

`Xblock = event.getX()/blockwidth + 1;` and similialy for Y

You may have to take border width and rest of the things to get correct Click Position to make the upper-left corner of your puzzle 0,0;

Comment: what would i set blockwidth equal to then?

Comment: suppose you have a puzzle of 90x90 pixels then each block would be 30x30 So `blockwidth /*(will be)*/ = 30 pixels.`

Comment: well i get a value but it changes when i click in different spots of the tile. does this have to do with the border width?

Comment: You should subtract the X and Y value obtained at clicking left top-left vertice of 1 tile from event.get(X and Y), that'll remove border etc.'s width

Comment: can I get puzzleLogic and Tile Class... Maybe on Pastebin?